# Compile Wireless 802.11 Subsystem in Linux

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel, compiling

I have modified the source code of cfg80211 in my vanilla Kernel and I want to compile only the wireless subsystem to avoid waiting for long time. I tried to remove the unnecessary drivers and modules in the `make menuconfig` however it still compiles a lot of non-related stuff to my work. Is there a way to compile just the wireless subsystem with its own drivers. In my case, the Atheros drivers only?

After successfully compiling the customized wireless subsystem I want to use the generated modules (Drivers) in my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 with Kernel 4.13

Comment: How this question is related to Ubuntu? You can always build single kernel modules, but the question is for [linux.se].

Comment: I added why it is related to Ubuntu somehow. But the question can be migrated to Unix & Linux too.

Comment: What you want to do is not possible.

Comment: @fkraiem it is possible, but on the same kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6 OP wants to do it on different kernels. Hence...

Comment: It is not clear that on different...

Comment: I want to do it on the same Kernel version

Comment: @Pilot6 I already did `make M=drivers/net/wireless/ath` and it complains that I did not find some scripts `scripts/genksyms/genksyms: not found`. I solved this by running make and when it starts executing the scripts mentioned I cancel and I execute the previous make command. So is there any cleaner way?

Comment: Solved `make prepare scripts`